# Is this a wild Muscadie/Scupernine Vine?

Tags: identification, grape-vine

Can anyone tell if this is a wild muscadine or scupernine vine? I live in SC and there are plenty wild on the property, but when I see those vines blooming, I also see vines and leaves that look very similar that don't have fruit on them. I don't know whether its a difference in sun, water, etc... or if one is just a different kind of vine.

I'm adding pictures of a vine that's growing very close to where I saw another one that has had fruit in a previous year. The are the wild ones and they're a dark burgundy/black fruit. Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image: muscadine]

It looks like it. Here's a picture of mine. Wild muscadine occurs as male or female, so if it doesn't produce fruit more than likely it's a male plant.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a muscadine to me too!  Lucky you, I wish I had these growing wild!